# Python script that pulls in and display a random xkcd comic

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

This script is supposed to download query xkcd json interface, find the total number of comics till date, pick a random number in that range, use the xkcd json interface again to find the comic image url, download it into `/tmp` filesystem, and use feh image viewer to display the image.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me if this program is neatly written

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib.request
import json
import random
import subprocess

class Xkcd :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.url = "https://xkcd.com/info.0.json"
        self.num_comics = None
        self.random_comic_num = None
        self.comic_json_url = None
        self.image_url = None

    def get_num_comics(self) :
        html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
        self.num_comics = json_data['num']

    def download_image(self) :
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.image_url, "/tmp/image")

    def get_random_comic(self) :
        self.get_num_comics()
        self.random_comic_num = random.randint(1, self.num_comics)
        self.comic_json_url = "https://xkcd.com/%s/info.0.json" %(self.random_comic_num)
        html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.comic_json_url)
        json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
        self.image_url = json_data['img']
        self.download_image()

    def show_image(self) :
        subprocess.Popen(["feh", "/tmp/image"])
        exit()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    ob = Xkcd()
    ob.get_random_comic()
    ob.show_image()
```

Comment: On the subject-matter side of things, not coding-style side of things, you might want to exclude some comics like [2601: Instructions](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2601:_Instructions) from your list of options.

Comment: FYI for this problem, no solution is complete without `import antigravity`

Comment: if you're fine opening it in a web browser this is all you need `webbrowser.open(f"https://xkcd.com/{random.randint(0, 2627)}")`

Comment: if you dont want to hard code 2627, you can grab the html for `www.xkcd.com`, check the <meta property="og:url" content="https://xkcd.com/2628/"> tag and grab the most recent value for your end in the randint call

Comment: I believe that RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the IEEE-vetted random number... you could probably make your code more performant by eliminating all of the `num_comics` stuff entirely and explicitly setting `self.random_comic_num=4` instead.  [Sorry - obligatory.](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Xkcd` as a class isn't particularly well-named: you're actually representing a "site", "session" or "downloader", distinct from an individual comic.

Its members are problematic. `url` never changes so should be moved to a static, but also `url` in its current form is only ever used once so instead you should store the base URL as a static and append paths to it as necessary.

`Xkcd`, upon construction, is broken and not ready to use. Exterior code that assumes that `num_comics` is valid will fail due to the None. An attempt to call `get_random_comic()` requires that it calls `get_num_comics`, and this will occur every single time that a comic is fetched. This should be cached instead.

`random_comic_num`, `comic_json_url` and `image_url` have no business existing as persistent members on the class; they should be passed around on a case-by-case basis as parameters and return values.

Avoid using `urllib` when `requests` does a better job.

Hard-coding `/tmp/image` is problematic: you're guaranteed to steamroll anything else at that path, including files from both your program and other programs that use that path. Also, some operating systems (a) cannot use that directory for temporary files, and (b) cannot infer from the extension-less path what mimetype the image is. The solution is to use the built-in temporary file support in Python and pass it a sane suffix.

It's relatively easy to capture the known properties of a returned JSON comic payload in a well-typed, well-defined class based off of a `NamedTuple` or dataclass, so do this.

It's also relatively easy to make `get_random_comic` more generally useful by making the "random" behaviour optional and accepting an optional index number. If that index number is `None` then the method can fill in a random index. Among other advantages, if the comic count logic is made lazy (which you should do anyway), then it will never be called so long as callers only want pre-defined indices.

Don't hard-code `feh`. If it isn't the default image viewer on your OS, that's a user problem and not a program problem. Instead make an attempt at using the default OS image viewer, though Python doesn't make this entirely easy to be portable: use `startfile` on Windows, `xdg-open` on Linux, `open` on Mac, etc. The latter two should be using `subprocess.check_call` with `shell=False`.

Your downloader/site class should have a `requests.Session` and it should be closeable via context management.

An algorithmic note: your random algorithm is reasonable but is not what the site itself uses. The site offers a link `https://c.xkcd.com/random/comic/` that takes your normal `GET` request and 302-redirects you to a random comic. Given that it requires the same number of network operations and gives you HTML rather than JSON, I think your count-and-choose method is still preferable.

### Suggested

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from functools import cache
from mimetypes import guess_type
from os import startfile
from os.path import basename
from random import randint
from shutil import copyfileobj
from subprocess import check_call
from sys import platform
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from typing import BinaryIO, NamedTuple

from requests import Session


class XkcdComic(NamedTuple):
    year: str
    month: str
    day: str
    num: int
    title: str
    safe_title: str
    link: str
    img: str
    news: str
    transcript: str
    alt: str

    @property
    def image_name(self) -> str:
        return basename(self.img)

    @property
    def image_mimetype(self) -> str:
        # typically image/png or image/jpeg
        mimetype, encoding = guess_type(self.img)
        return mimetype


class XkcdSite:
    BASE_URL = 'https://xkcd.com/'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.session = Session()

        def get_count() -> int:
            return self.get_current_comic().num
        self.get_num_comics = cache(get_count)

    def __enter__(self) -> 'XkcdSite':
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) -> None:
        self.session.close()

    def get_image(self, comic: XkcdComic, file: BinaryIO) -> None:
        with self.session.get(
            url=comic.img,
            headers={'Accept': comic.image_mimetype},
            stream=True,
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            copyfileobj(response.raw, file)

    def get_comic(self, index: int) -> XkcdComic:
        return self._fetch_comic(prefix=f'{index}/')

    def get_current_comic(self) -> XkcdComic:
        return self._fetch_comic(prefix='')

    def get_random_comic(self) -> XkcdComic:
        return self.get_comic(index=randint(1, self.get_num_comics()))

    def _fetch_comic(self, prefix: str) -> XkcdComic:
        with self.session.get(
            url=f'{self.BASE_URL}{prefix}info.0.json',
            headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return XkcdComic(**response.json())

    def show_image(self, comic: XkcdComic) -> None:
        with NamedTemporaryFile(
            # Needed for Windows since startfile() cannot block
            delete=False,
            # Needed for Windows since it cannot guess mimetypes based on content alone
            suffix='_' + comic.image_name,
        ) as file:
            self.get_image(comic, file)
            run_file(file.name)


def run_file(path: str) -> None:
    if platform == 'win32':  # Windows
        startfile(path)
    else:  # assume Linux-like
        check_call(('/usr/bin/xdg-open', path), shell=False)
    # This does not cover darwin/mac ('open'), etc.


def main() -> None:
    with XkcdSite() as site:
        comic = site.get_random_comic()
        site.show_image(comic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know that I'd agree with "Avoid using `urllib` when `requests` does a better job." `urllib` is part of the stdlib while `requests` is not.

Comment: @Skyler You're right that requests is not built in. That said, it's not a difficult package to install nor an uncommon package to depend upon, and [the Python documentation itself recommends it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

Answer (score 10):

The use of a class here is basically strictly a bad idea. This is such a simple script that if I were actually writing it, I would probably just put all the code under `if __name__ == "__main__" :` with no functions or classes at all. Of course, since you're posting here you're probably at least partly writing this as an intellectual exercise, but even with with that parameter, using a class here really does nothing but make the code worse, for reasons I'll explain in a second. First I'll post how I would prefer to structure it. In the spirit of this being an exercise, I will actually split it up into functions in what I think is a reasonable way:

```
def random_comic_url():
    url = "https://xkcd.com/info.0.json"
    html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
    num_comics = json_data['num']
    random_comic_num = random.randint(1, num_comics)
    comic_json_url = "https://xkcd.com/%s/info.0.json" % (self.random_comic_num)
    html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(comic_json_url)
    json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
    image_url = json_data['img']
    return image_url

def show_image(image_url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "/tmp/image")
    subprocess.Popen(["feh", "/tmp/image"])
    exit()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = random_comic_url()
    show_image(url)
```

I figure I'll turn this into a little case study in when and when not to use a class. Here are bad reasons to use a class:

- Because I just thought of a noun that seems intuitively related to the problem, so it should be a class.
- Because I'm writing a function, and every function should be in a class, because that's cleaner, right?

Here is the only reason you actually should use a class:

- You have a bunch of functions whose behavior needs to depend on which order the *other* functions got called in previously (and with what arguments), and *it makes sense to call those functions in all kinds of different orders*.

This is just a very abstract way of saying that you have a bunch of functions whose behavior depends on some piece of state, and such that only those functions are able to modify that state. The problem here is that the italicized part does not apply to our situation. Yes, the behavior of your `show_image()` method will depend on which of the other methods you called previously, but only in the sense that it doesn't make sense to call it at all if you haven't called all of the other methods.

This gets to the heart of the biggest problem with unnecessary use of classes: you're adding opportunities for your code to be put into an illegal state. In your case, it doesn't make sense to call `get_num_comics()`, `get_random_comic()`, `download_image()` and `show_image()` in anything other than that order. But how would a user of your class (including you in a week, when you've forgotten the details) know that? They're likely to forget to call one, and end up causing a crash. They'll need to discover how the code is to be used through trial and error, or you'll have to write documentation.

If it only ever makes sense to call `f1`, `f2` and `f3` in that order, you may as well concatenate them together into one big function. If for reasons of readability you want to keep them as three separate functions, the thing to do is have `f1` return a value which gets passed to `f2`, and so on, not put them in a class. This way, it is actually impossible for someone using your code to call `f2` without calling `f1` first. This is why I split the code into two functions in the way that I did. If for example I had a function `download_random_comic()` and a function `show_image()` which accepts no argument, this would have been bad because calling `show_image()` without calling `download_random_comic()` first would be an error.

If the functions could be called in an arbitrary order but don't depend on one another, just make them functions. If the functions could be called in an arbitrary order, and their behavior depends on the order the other functions were called in previously, *then* it should be a class. You might wonder: but why would we ever not know in what order some functions are going to get called? It's our code, we know everything about it. There are two reasons:

1. Because the order depends on the result of I/O. I/O here means anything that you can't know while writing the code: contents of files the program might read, what order the user clicks the buttons in, etc.
2. Because we are *pretending* not to know the order so that when we use the functions, we know that we won't accidentally cause bugs by calling them in the wrong order, and so that if the code later changes so they have to get called in a different order, we won't have to re-write this part of the code.

A testament to what kinds of problems unnecessary state can cause is is that while I was writing the classless version above, it was actually quite difficult for me to cut-and-paste the code together in a way that would work, because of the way the state is kind of bouncing around all over the place in your class. I start writing the `random_comic_url()` function and go look up how you generate the random comic number, and I see you're depending on `self.num_comics` (worse, you're depending on it *through* and accessor function, meaning I have to read through yet another layer of indirection). So now I have to scan through the class looking for how that field is populated. I look at `get_num_comics()`, and it depends on `self.url`, so I have to go look up how *that* field gets its value. In this simple example this is annoying but ultimately it just means I have to scroll around more: I just look up the one place in the class where you populate that field. In a more complicated class, it would be a disaster, because for every one of those fields, I have to anticipate *every possible way* that field could have gotten a value, and basically mentally plot a kind of exponentially growing possibility tree of all the possible paths that could have been taken: `num_comics` has three different ways to get a value, one of which depends on the value of `url`, and `url` can get a value in four different ways, etc... This is fine if the logic that the code is implementing really is just that complicated, and the code merely reflects that, but for this problem there is actually only one possible execution path by which `url` and `num_comics` can get their value. In a straight-line "functional" version of the code, that knowledge about the program is made explicit and visible at a glance. In the stateful, class-based version, that knowledge is destroyed, and the programmer has to reconstruct it by carefully reading the code.

Another disadvantage to putting things in classes when they don't need to be is that you are coupling things together that don't need to be coupled. If you look at my implementation above, we've decoupled the code that displays an image from the code that gets an XKCD comic url. After all, showing an image from a URL really has nothing to do with JSON or XKCD. If later you want to extend the code to also display other webcomics, it will be very obvious how to do so: since `show_image()` accepts an image URL as argument, you just need to write code to get a URL to the image of the new comic, and pass it to `show_image()`. With the class-based implementation, you would be forced to read the class, un-pick the image rendering code form the network and JSON code, and then split the two apart as I did when I wrote this post, which as I commented above, actually turned out to be a slightly annoying process.

An epilogue: now that we understand when classes are appropriate, we can actually take a second look at the problem we're trying to solve here. There actually *is* one way in which this problem has some state which could be nicely modelled as a class. This potential statefulness actually comes not from code architecture concerns, but from code *performance* concerns. If you look at my code, it has to download the main JSON file and figure out how many XKCD comics there are every time you want to download a new random comic. This is a little bit inefficient. In cases like this where you have a function  (my `random_comic_url()` function) which does some initial relatively heavy work that strictly only needs to be done once, and then does some extra, lighter work, a pattern you can apply is to make that function the sole method of a very small class. The heavy work happens in the class constructor. If we apply this pattern here, we get something like this:

```
class RandomXKCDSource:

    def __init__(self):
        url = "https://xkcd.com/info.0.json"
        html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
        self.num_comics = json_data['num']
        
    def random_comic_url(self):
        random_comic_num = random.randint(1, self.num_comics)
        comic_json_url = "https://xkcd.com/%s/info.0.json" % (random_comic_num)
        html_data = urllib.request.urlopen(comic_json_url)
        json_data = json.loads(html_data.read())
        image_url = json_data['img']
        return image_url
```

In terms of our "bunch of functions depending on eachother which could be called in any order" model, the "in any order" component is subtle here: it comes down to the fact that we don't know *how many times* `random_comic_url()` will be called. If we knew it would only be called once, then there would be no performance loss in merging both these functions into one.

Of course, you could also just have a function that calculates the number of comics, and then pass that number as an argument to a function `random_comic_url()`. Now you can call it as many times as you want without re-calculating the number of comics. In many cases, that would be a bette way to write the code, but the class-based way doesn't have *no* advtanges. One advantage is that you can construct an instance of this class and pass it off to another piece of code, and that one object has everything that code needs to get a random URL: you don't need to pass a second variable around. Another advantage is that you are allowing the `random_comic_url()` to have an *arbitrarily complicated* "startup routine". Right now the "startup routine" is calculating the number of comics. But maybe XKCD changes their API at some point, and while you still need to do some heavy computations which you only have to do once up-front, the result of those computations no longer takes the form of a number of comics. Then you can just change what happens in the constructor, and code using this class doesn't have to know.

And of course, remember that at the end of the day, the *actual* correct way to write a script this simple, if we were really just trying to solve the actual problem and not as a code design exercise (and we were sure this script wasn't going to grow into a bigger project), was just to put it all inline in one script. Good formatting and good variable names give you all the readability you need in a script this short.

Comment: Hard disagree on a lot of this. _If it only ever makes sense to call f1, f2 and f3 in that order, you may as well concatenate them together into one big function_ is a great recipe to produce untestable, non-maintainable code. You are not the compiler: if your concern is that multiple functions produce call overhead, that's surely premature optimisation.

Comment: _I would probably just put all the code under `if __name__ == "__main__" :` with no functions or classes at all_ is a bad idea for a whole rainbow of reasons, including: the purpose of a main guard is to allow importers to execute your functions selectively while avoiding the entry point. If you have no functions or classes, it's pointless to have a main guard.

Comment: _The use of a class here is basically strictly a bad idea_ does not hold water generally. If you're playing code golf, then perhaps. But it's so little effort to write a strong API client that doesn't need to be trashed when your use case changes, that.. why not? Simmering the application down to only exactly what you need right at this very moment with no care for generalisation or future-you seems myopic.

Comment: @Reinderien https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0

Comment: @Reinderien Nothing to do with mere number of lines of code. C.f. everything I wrote in my answer. The concern with having code unnecessarily split into functions has nothing to do with call overhead, again c.f. everything I said about illegal states/implicit preconditions in my answer. The advice I give in this answer has everything to do *with* making the code *more* readable and maintainable, not less - again, see everything I said in my answer.

Comment: agree with concatenating stuff together being a bad idea. splitting code into manageably-sized functions has ***everything*** to do with readability, even if just for the visual separation between different sections.

Comment: @Reinderien *The use of a class here is strictly a good idea* does not hold water generally. If you're prematurely feature-creeping, then perhaps. But it's so little effort to ***not*** write a class just because "classes good" that... why not? Adding redundant structure to an application that will ***never*** be used since this would in almost no cases need *any* kind of persistent state whatsoever seems myopic.